# Is it possible to transfer a sitecore site to umbraco

Tags: sitecore, umbraco, transfer

I have clients who are using sitecore for their site. Its over bloated and much more than they need. I am redesigning their site in wordpress, no problem. However they have certain 'tools' setup that they want to keep, so Im wondering if I can transfer them to Umbraco or any CMS that doesn't have a hefty license fee!

The sitecore license is due to be renewed for another year, and Im trying to find a stop gap so we dont have to pay... can you transfer the whole site easily to umbraco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you are likely to be able to get is the raw content of the site as XML. You can then run that through some XSLT to generate an input XML format for Umbraco.

Alternatively, use `wget` to spider the website and generate a whole load of HTML, and then copy/paste that back into the new CMS. Sounds painful, but it's often what's needed in these migrations (I have resorted to that for several clients).

Comment: In the same vain do you have any experience moving the database over to something like wordpress? Im thinking of logins specifically.

Comment: The WordPress import is actually pretty impressive. I have moved entire blogs including comments and users from Blogger to WordPress and it "just works". If the XML export is in a standard format (say RSS), then you'll have no trouble with a WordPress import

Comment: Just what I wanted to hear! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did that once. Implementation partner converted all the templates and gave me an xml output. Then I used [CMSImport](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/cmsimport) (Disclaimer: I'm the author of that package don't need to use it but it's quite handy) for Umbraco to import the data.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I saw that tool. Is it straight forward to convert the templates? You will have to forgive me, I have limited experience with .net, Im a linux man! Do you know of any idiots guides to the transfer?